# What java view technology is this?

Tags: java, jsp, templates, jstl, el

It seems velocity and freemarker look fairly similiar, at least for basic usage.

Anyhow, what is the "built in" or standard view framework called? 
It looks like:

```
<c:if test="${someobject.property != null}">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's indeed [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/). It's however not builtin, but all you need to do is to just drop [jstl-1.2.jar](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) in the `/WEB-INF/lib` and declare one of its taglibs in top of the JSP page as per the TLD documentation, e.g. [JSTL core](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

This way you can use the in the link listed tags. Most of the [core tags](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnakh.html) are just flow control tags. JSTL also has [XML](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/x/tld-summary.html) and [SQL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/sql/tld-summary.html) taglibs, but they are intented for quick prototyping only and shouldn't be used in real production. Then there is the [Format (fmt)](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/tld-summary.html) taglib which is great for [internationalization and localization](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnakw.html) (i18n and l10n). Finally there is the useful [functions (fn)](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html) taglib which provides simple EL functions.

Then there are the `${}` things. This is called [expression language](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html). It just accesses "backend data" (the attributes) in any of the page, request, session and application scopes in a Javabean like way with help of [`PageContext#findAttribute()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#findAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) and calling the Javabean **getters**. If you understand *scriptlets*, then you'll understand the following example:

```
${user.address.street}
```

which roughly resolves to

```
<%= pageContext.findAttrubute("user").getAddress().getStreet() %>
```

EL is **nullsafe**. When `${user}` or `${user.address}` resolves to `null`, then it will just skip it all and display nothing. In *scriptlets* you would have gotten a NPE on the nested calls or just plain `null` on the last call.

Then there is the unified EL, denoted by the `#{}` syntax. It's (as far) only used in combination with [JavaServer Faces (JSF)](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/bnaph.html). It is able do to a call a Javabean **setter** on the *last* property. E.g.

```
<h:inputText name="foo" value="#{bean.foo}">
```

will behind the scenes roughly do like follows

```
pageContext.findAttribute("bean").setFoo(request.getParameter("foo"));
```

It's by the way not a *view technology*. JSP itself is already the view technology at its own. JSTL is just a *taglib*. EL is just part of the JSP spec. The other view technology provided by Java EE is [Facelets](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/giepx.html) which is XHTML based and provides much more seamless integration for JSF than JSP does.

Answer (score 6):

It's most likely [Unified Expression Language (EL)](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/reference/techart/unifiedEL.html) which is used by [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/).

I think it would look more like

```
<c:if test="${someobject.property != null}">
```